# Drawer navigation React Native Expo build doesnt play animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, xiaomi

After building project using
`eas build -p andriod --profile preview`
my drawer navigation doesnt play animation, its stack.

[gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcHHO.gif)

eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android" : {
        "buildType" : "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Its happens only in 1 mobile (Xiaomi POCO F4 MiUI 14). And sometimes this problem disappear. And after rebooting phone also its working fine. But after few restarts of the program its will broken again. What should i do? Maybe its some setting enabled in my phone?

```
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
```

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

import { HomeScreen } from './screens/screenA';
import { NotificationsScreen } from './screens/screenB';

export default function App() {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
     </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}
```